# How does SGC know who is incoming before the stargate connects?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

At the start of [season 1, episode 19 - Solitudes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0709175/) of Stargate SG1, before the title credits, there is an incoming wormhole which for some reason destablizes and disconnects before the entire team gets through. However, before the connection is initially established, the following happens:

> *stargate is currently locking chevrons for an incoming connection*
>   **General Hammond**: There's no one scheduled to come back for 24 hours, who is it?
>   **Walter Harriman**: It's SG-1's remote access code, Sir.
>   *stargate connects*

This occurs more frequently much later in the series but I always passed that off as Earth's military technology having improved over the duration of the show, however this is really early on and they haven't gained anything like that technology by this point.

How does SGC know who is incoming before the stargate connects?

Comment: That's funny about the episode numbering ... IMDB shows it as episode 17, you are saying episode 19, and the DVD's show it as episode 18.

Comment: Heh... episode 18 was Tin Man for me... o.O

Comment: I think I know what the issue is here ... the first episode was a 2-hour episode. It was later split into two parts when it went into syndication. Here's the [card from the boxed set](http://www.paulster2.com/images/Stuff/20150512_080045.jpg). That would have pushed all of the numbers out one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a similar question posted on [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59625/how-can-the-identification-code-be-received-before-the-wormhole-is-created). Please note that there might be some spoilers in the question and/or the answer.

The answers suggest that there can be two possibilities:

1. The dialing in itself may carry some additional information - in this case the SG team codes.
2. It's an error in editing of the episodes.

Comment: It's been a while since I watched the show, but as I recall, they state somewhere in the series that radio waves can travel through the Stargate before the worm hole is completely formed.

Answer (score 6):

The remote access code is provided through a device which one of the Stargate team members wears on their arm. After the wormhole is established, the team member punches in the access code, it is transmitted back through the wormhole, the SGC picks up the signal, verifies it's a valid code and which team it belongs to, then they open the iris on the gate. This isn't *new* technology, just a *new use* of Earth technology. The transmitter looks like this and is worn on the arm, usually Dr. Carter of the SG-1 team:

[image]

Comment: In this particular episode, though, the wormhole isn't established - the code is received and verified by the SGC as chevron 6 locks.